# Problem with casting from an object storing a list of value types to a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have a function that takes object as an input. Only List< T > of various T will be passed here as the type, but **the argument needs to stay as object** for some external/API reasons.

```
void Receive(object collection)
```

Let's not discuss that this is a bad design :) Assume that this is a constraint.

The situation is as follows.
I want to cast or convert my parameter to an enumerable (or a list could do too) of objects this time.
Again, it must be enumerable/list of objects, not of the specific type. Partly because I don't know the exact type.

```
void Receive(object collection)
{
   var myList = (IEnumerable<object>)collection;
}
```

What boggles me is that this only seems to work with reference types.
It works when called like this:

```
 Receive(new List<Foo>() { new Foo()}}
```

It does not work when called like this:

```
Receive(new List<int>() {2}
Receive(new List<(int,int)>() {(5,9)}
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]

I guess this is related to the lack of some conversion operator for value types.

***Question:***

How to cast it, so it works when either a list of reference types or value types is passed as the argument?

I have seen people having similar issues when casting a list of specific type to a list of objects but this is easy (e.g. we can use ToList). My situation is more difficult because I don't have the IEnumerable in the first place to call any methods. I only have the object, so I need to do some kind of casting first.

Comment: You can't cast as that type. I was going to suggest casting as `IEnumerable` as in the answer provided, because you can still enumerate that and get an `object` reference for each item. If you really need an `IEnumerable<object>` for some reason, you can create a new object of that type like so: `var myList = ((IEnumerable)collection).Cast<object>();`. That will box each value in the list and create a new enumerable object over them.

Answer (score 4):

> How to cast it

You are already getting error, it means that's impossible. You need to change your approach.

I propose to convert the collection to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`. You can use it in foreach operation and treat the items as object.

```
public void Receive(object collection)
{
    var myList = (IEnumerable)collection;
    
    // value is object here
    foreach(var value in myList)
    {

    }
}
```